# displaying input field after clicking button react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning react-native and I wanted to do something simple where the user can enter some information like name or something and then when he/she clicks the button, it will display on the screen hello so and so. I have my `onChangeText` setting the `state` to what the user passes but it doesn't update. Also clicking the button doesn't show anything. I will paste my code down below. Any help or suggestions.

`app.js`

```
import { Button } from "react-native";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Alert,
  TextInput
} from "react-native";

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: "Press Cmd+R to reload,\n" + "Cmd+D or shake for dev menu",
  android:
    "Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n" +
    "Shake or press menu button for dev menu"
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      text: "Hello "
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = typedText => {
    this.setState({
      text: typedText
    });
    console.log(text);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{this.state.value}</Text>
        <Button onPress={this.handleChange} title="Click Me " />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Type your name here"
          onChangeText={typedText => {
            this.setState({
              text: typedText
            });
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#333333",
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});
```

Comment: where is the onhelloFunction function ?

Comment: should of been `handleChange`. Updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the state in handlechange (the onpress function) as well which is not required at all. There wont be an argument of text in your onPress you are resetting the text value in the state. And the text inside the handleChange will be undefined as you dont set it anywhere.

the code should be something like below.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      text: "Hello "
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  onPress = () => {
    console.log("current ==> ", this.state);
    alert(this.state.text);
  };
  handleChange = typedText => {
    console.log("update => ", typedText);
    this.setState(
      {
        text: typedText
      }
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{this.state.value}</Text>
        <Button onPress={this.onPress} title="Click Me " />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Type your name here"
          onChangeText={this.handleChange}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont see any changes happening when button is clicked

Comment: replace the console.log(this.state.text); with alert(this.state.text);

Comment: when I type it keeps alerting `hello`. So every time the state changes it alerts instead of waiting till im done typing and clicking the button

Comment: Yes this is perfect. The only thing is that I would like to have `hello` then whatever the user passes. Right now it just shows what the user passes.

Comment: you could do alert("Hello"+this.state.text);

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, on Press of button we are calling a function which expects a 'text' but in actual it is an event.
Check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/42qm1z2m19)

Comment: Your code doesn't output anything when the button `click me` is clicked

Comment: @moegizzle check in console. It shows the current text. When you update the text, that is set to state

Comment: I am using a iphone emulator?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check in emulator, as I have not worked in react-native. You can try to see the state or show a popup in the change handler to see that state is being updated.